# When I click cancel for a brief period, the keyboard stays up

Tags: react-native

When I click to search the keyboard comes up. However, when I click cancel for a brief period, the keyboard stays up while I see the home page.

Navigating back from search page still shows the keyboard for few moments how to remove it

[image: a]

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import {
    StyleSheet,
    View,
    Text,
    Button,
    Alert,
    Image,
    TextInput
} from "react-native";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import { SafeAreaView } from "react-navigation";

import { scale, verticalScale } from "@helpers/scale";
import Colors from "@app/app.colors";
import ClickView from "@components/widgets/ClickView";
import Fonts from "@config/fonts";
import images from "@assets/images";
import * as uiconstant from "@constants/ui.constant";

export class SearchScreen extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            text: ""
        };
    }

    static navigationOptions = {
        tabBarVisible: false
    };

    renderSearchTextContainer() {
        return (
            <View style={styles.searchTextContainer}>
                <Image
                    style={{ marginLeft: scale(6) }}
                    source={images.searchIcon}
                />
                <TextInput
                    style={{ flex: 1, marginLeft: scale(7), height: scale(40) }}
                    placeholder="e.g., Cryptography"
                    onChangeText={text => this.setState({ text })}
                    value={this.state.text}
                    keyboardType="default"
                    returnKeyType="search"
                    underlineColorAndroid="transparent"
                    autoFocus={true}
                    multiline={false}
                    onSubmitEditing={_ => {
                        console.log("return tapped");
                        if (
                            this.state.text !== "" &&
                            this.state.text !== null
                        ) {
                            this.props.navigation.navigate("searchResult", {
                                searchText: this.state.text
                            });
                        }
                    }}
                />
                <ClickView
                    style={styles.removeButtonStyle}
                    onPress={_ => {
                        // let oldString = this.state.text;
                        // newString = oldString.slice(0, -1);
                        this.setState({
                            text: ""
                        });
                    }}
                >
                    <Image source={images.cancelIcon} />
                </ClickView>
            </View>
        );
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <SafeAreaView style={[styles.safeAreaContainer]}>
                <View style={styles.container}>
                    <View style={styles.searchContainer}>
                        {this.renderSearchTextContainer()}
                        <ClickView
                            style={styles.cancelButtonStyle}
                            onPress={_ => {
                                this.props.navigation.goBack();
                            }}
                        >
                            <Text style={styles.cancelTextStyle}>Cancel</Text>
                        </ClickView>
                    </View>
                </View>
                <View
                    style={{
                        flex: 1,
                        backgroundColor: Colors.backgroundColor
                    }}
                />
            </SafeAreaView>
        );
    }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    safeAreaContainer: {
        flex: 1,
        backgroundColor: Colors.white
    },
    container: {
        backgroundColor: Colors.white,
        borderBottomWidth: 1.0,
        borderBottomColor: Colors.athensGray
    },
    searchTextContainer: {
        flex: 1,
        flexDirection: "row",
        borderColor: Colors.athensGray,
        borderRadius: 2,
        borderWidth: 1,
        overflow: "hidden",
        alignItems: "center"
    },
    removeButtonStyle: {
        marginLeft: scale(2),
        marginRight: scale(2),
        width: 30,
        height: 30,
        justifyContent: "center",
        alignItems: "center"
    },
    cancelButtonStyle: {
        alignSelf: "center",
        width: scale(52),
        height: scale(37),
        marginLeft: scale(6),
        justifyContent: "center",
        alignItems: "center"
    },
    cancelTextStyle: {
        fontFamily: Fonts.Semibold,
        fontSize: scale(15),
        color: Colors.slateGray
    },
    searchContainer: {
        marginTop: verticalScale(10),
        marginBottom: verticalScale(10),
        height: scale(37),
        marginLeft: scale(14),
        marginRight: scale(17),

        flexDirection: "row"
    }
});
```

Whenever i type the search text or even simply click on the Cancel button.
Here i have written the code for the search page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can import keyboard from react native which provides you with several functions. One of which is dismiss, this function can be used to hide the keyboard. So whenever you are navigating the screen, before navigating call the dismiss function of keyboad. You can do as below:-

```
import {Keyboard} from "react-native";
```

when you are navigating to different screen, call the below function before navigating:-

```
Keyboard.dismiss();
```

**EDIT**

You can navigate your screen inside on submit editing after a timeout of 100ms so that keyboard.dismiss function is executed as below:-

```
onSubmitEditing = {_ => {
    console.log("return tapped");
    if (this.state.text !== "" && this.state.text !== null) {
        Keyboard.dismiss();
        setTimeout(_ => {
            this.props.navigation.navigate("searchResult", {searchText: this.state.text});
        }, 100)
    }
}}
```

Comment: Had already used this before, but itseems it doesnt work as intended. Is there any work around for this?

Comment: What happens if you use keyboard.dismiss ? Is your keyboard still open?

Comment: keyboard dismiss will close the keyboard but after navigating to the home page. I want to close the keyboard and then navigate to the home page

Comment: I also tried adding the code in the home page inside componentDidMount() but still didnt work

Comment: Your screen is navigating before the dismiss function is being executed, so you can use timeout of 100ms for this.

Comment: can you please help me with the setTimeout function i am confused.

Comment: I have updated the answer above, please find it and let me know if you want any other help.

Answer (score 0):

use keyboard.dismiss().
import Keyboard from react native and call dismiss function.

```
 import React, { Component } from "react";
 import {
     StyleSheet,
     View,
     Text,
     Button,
     Alert,
     Image,
     TextInput,
    Keyboard
} from "react-native";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import { SafeAreaView } from "react-navigation";

import { scale, verticalScale } from "@helpers/scale";
import Colors from "@app/app.colors";
import ClickView from "@components/widgets/ClickView";
import Fonts from "@config/fonts";
import images from "@assets/images";
import * as uiconstant from "@constants/ui.constant";

export class SearchScreen extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            text: ""
        };
    }

    static navigationOptions = {
        tabBarVisible: false
    };

    renderSearchTextContainer() {
        return (
            <View style={styles.searchTextContainer}>
                <Image
                    style={{ marginLeft: scale(6) }}
                    source={images.searchIcon}
                />
                <TextInput
                    style={{ flex: 1, marginLeft: scale(7), height: scale(40) }}
                    placeholder="e.g., Cryptography"
                    onChangeText={text => this.setState({ text })}
                    value={this.state.text}
                    keyboardType="default"
                    returnKeyType="search"
                    underlineColorAndroid="transparent"
                    autoFocus={true}
                    multiline={false}
                    onSubmitEditing={_ => {
                        console.log("return tapped");
                        if (
                            this.state.text !== "" &&
                            this.state.text !== null
                        ) {
                            Keyboard.dismiss();
                            setTimeout(()=>this.props.navigation.navigate("searchResult", {
                                searchText: this.state.text
                            }), 500);
                        }
                    }}
                />
                <ClickView
                    style={styles.removeButtonStyle}
                    onPress={_ => {
                        // let oldString = this.state.text;
                        // newString = oldString.slice(0, -1);
                        this.setState({
                            text: ""
                        });
                    }}
                >
                    <Image source={images.cancelIcon} />
                </ClickView>
            </View>
        );
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <SafeAreaView style={[styles.safeAreaContainer]}>
                <View style={styles.container}>
                    <View style={styles.searchContainer}>
                        {this.renderSearchTextContainer()}
                        <ClickView
                            style={styles.cancelButtonStyle}
                            onPress={_ => {
                                this.props.navigation.goBack();
                            }}
                        >
                            <Text style={styles.cancelTextStyle}>Cancel</Text>
                        </ClickView>
                    </View>
                </View>
                <View
                    style={{
                        flex: 1,
                        backgroundColor: Colors.backgroundColor
                    }}
                />
            </SafeAreaView>
        );
    }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    safeAreaContainer: {
        flex: 1,
        backgroundColor: Colors.white
    },
    container: {
        backgroundColor: Colors.white,
        borderBottomWidth: 1.0,
        borderBottomColor: Colors.athensGray
    },
    searchTextContainer: {
        flex: 1,
        flexDirection: "row",
        borderColor: Colors.athensGray,
        borderRadius: 2,
        borderWidth: 1,
        overflow: "hidden",
        alignItems: "center"
    },
    removeButtonStyle: {
        marginLeft: scale(2),
        marginRight: scale(2),
        width: 30,
        height: 30,
        justifyContent: "center",
        alignItems: "center"
    },
    cancelButtonStyle: {
        alignSelf: "center",
        width: scale(52),
        height: scale(37),
        marginLeft: scale(6),
        justifyContent: "center",
        alignItems: "center"
    },
    cancelTextStyle: {
        fontFamily: Fonts.Semibold,
        fontSize: scale(15),
        color: Colors.slateGray
    },
    searchContainer: {
        marginTop: verticalScale(10),
        marginBottom: verticalScale(10),
        height: scale(37),
        marginLeft: scale(14),
        marginRight: scale(17),

        flexDirection: "row"
    }
});
```

Comment: Had already used this before, but itseems it doesnt work as intended. Is there any work around for this?

Comment: A small hack. use setTimeout. I updated the code. Try it. If you need more time increase 500.

Comment: can you please help me with the setTimeout function  i am confused